# Find 2 adjacent points to complete a square

Tags: java, algorithm, math, geometry

I am looking for something [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/506853), but that answer applies for when the two points are opposite each other on a square. How would you find the other two points when the given points are adjacent to each other?

For example, if given the input (0,0), (1,0), the method would output both (0,1), (1,1) and (0, -1), (-1,-1) because both of these sets of points would create squares.

Comment: The same way you get the points with pen and paper. You just need to translate your every-day logic to code. Try it, it's good for you!

Comment: @Gendarme I'm not sure what "every-day logic" you are talking about. I thought about using the distance between the two points given to find the hypotenuse, but that can only be used to check whether or not the points form a square, not actually finding the points.

Comment: @DovshmuelLeumhsvod You would be able to find the points of the square if I gave you two points on a paper. The same logic you use to find the points with pen and paper, you use when calculating the points with a Java program.

Comment: @Gendarme That's what I'm asking -- I know I can solve it using pen and paper, I just don't know how I would write it into an algorithm. Maybe the example I gave was too easy since all it involves is switching the positions of the x and y coordinate and finding the inverse, but how would it work if I gave points (0,0), (2,1)?

Comment: (0,0), (2,1) => (-1,2), (1,3) and (1,-2), (3,-1). It's easier than you think.

Comment: @Beta Yes, a five year old could figure that out by plotting it out. I'm trying to find out what the most efficient way is to come to that answer. Did you  use Pythagorean theorem? Did you use the distance formula? Did you use vectors? Did you have to use trigonometric functions?

Comment: I did not use trigonometry, I did not calculate a distance, I did not take a square root. I used vectors. If you understand the basics of vectors, this is a simple problem; if you don't, it will be a headache. (0,0), (a,b) => (-b,a), (a-b, a+b) and (b, -a), (a+b, -a+b)

Comment: @Beta Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I haven't learned about vectors in school yet.

Comment: that solution works only in 2D for 3D or more you need to use cross product. btw the solution is based on simple 90 deg rotation around `a` or `b` ... there are `sin` and `cos`  involved but with angle `90deg` which leads to `0` and `1` .... so rotated point `(x,y)` around `(0,0)`  by `90` deg is `(-y,x)`  and `(y,-x)` depends on direction you  rotate CW/CCW ...

Comment: @Beta How do you solve it if one of the coordinates is not (0,0)? For example, how would you calculate (2,0), (3,2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(a,b), (c,d) => (a+b-d, -a+b+c), (b+c-d, -a+c+d) and (a-b+d, a+b-c), (-b+c+d, a-c+d)
```

For example,

```
(2,0), (3,2) => (0,1), (1,3) => and (4,-1), (5,1)
```